# How to approach string formatting in templates

Tags: templates, go

I pass a struct to a template that sometimes contain strings that are a tad too long for display. In any other language, I would've just attached a formatting rule in the template itself. What's the idiomatic approach to accomplish formatting in templates?

Example:

```
type struct MyStruct{
    something    string
    anotherThing string
}
```

*In the template*

```
<table>
{{ range .Rows }}      //NOTE! Rows is an array of MyStruct objects 
<tr>
<td>{{ .something }}</td>
<td>{{ .anotherThing }}</td>        
</tr>
{{ end }}
</table>
```

In case it isn't obvious from the above, the question is "How would you go about making sure .anotherThing or .something doesn't display more than say 40 characters?

One solution COULD be to make the struct contain four values, the two raw strings and two formatted version of them i.e. make the formatting in the .go-file and then always display the raw string in a tooltip on hover or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a custom truncate function to the [FuncMap](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap). Someone posted an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/z-yyM6mVt8) on the playground, which converts template variables to uppercase, like this:

```
{{ .Name | ToUpper  }}
```

Edit. Adjusted above code as a basic `Truncate` filter: http://play.golang.org/p/e0eaf-fyrH

```
{{ .Name | Truncate  }}
```

If you want to pass a parameter to `Truncate`, you'll can also write it like this:

```
{{ Truncate .Name 3 }}
```

See also: http://play.golang.org/p/Gh3JY1wzcF

Comment: I've seen this before but it seems like an awfully backward way of accomplishing something that should be easy. I'd almost rather extend my struct instead with raw + formatted values then. Thanks just the same for offering an answer.

Comment: @Adergaard Well, if you do this to your data, then you would mix your display logic with your data and duplicate it. I'd advise against it. Use the template functions. This is the clean approach.

Comment: Yes. You are probably right. I'm setting this to correct.

Answer (score 1):

One approach besides using a custom function is defining your own type with the `Stringer` interface:

```
type ShortString string

func(ss ShortString) String() string {
    if len(ss) > 10 {
        return string(ss[:5]) + "..."
    }
    return string(ss)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Something    ShortString
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/GUJK6Y6m8D) displaying both approaches.